# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroid/content/Context;

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, android-studio-3.0

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError Exception while trying to @Mock Context in Test class

Gradle detail :

```
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.ssl"
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 18
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
}
```

Test class detail :

```html
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class VehicleSingleTest {
    private VehicleSingle mVehicleSingle;
    @Mock
Context context;
   
@Before
public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

dependency detail for Junit and Mokito :

```html
 
compile files('libs/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar')
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'`enter code here`
```

**Full Exception log**

```html
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77) at
org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70) at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.
<init>(TestClass.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.
  <init>(ParentRunner.java:83) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.
    <init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65) at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.
      <init>(JUnit4.java:22) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104) at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59) at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26) at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33) at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49) at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.content.Context at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```